# Impossible to access an attribute ("nom_entite") on a string variable ("Showig Array

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to get the list of all element from my entity "Entite".

i hace in my Repository:

```
 public function findAll(){
    $stmt = $this->getEntityManager()
    ->getConnection()
    ->prepare('select * from Entite ');
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    return ( array('name' => 'Showig '. print_r($result,true)));
}
```

in my controller:

```
public function listAction(){

    $manageur = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $listEntite = $manageur->getRepository("acmeBundle:Entite")->findAll();

    return $this->render("acmeBundle:admin:listBu.html.twig",array("liste"=>$listEntite));
}
```

and in my twig i have this :

```
  {% for entite in liste %}
    <tr> <td> {{ entite.nom_entite ~ " " }} </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> {{ entite.nom_agence ~ " " }} </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> {{ entite.entite_abrev ~ " " }} </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> {{ entite.entite_niveau ~ " " }} </td> </tr>
   {% endfor %}
```

i get this exception :

```
    Impossible to access an attribute ("nom_entite") on a string variable ("Showig 

Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[id] => 1
[nom_entite] => llll
[nom_agence] => 0
[entite_abrev] => fff
[entite_niveau] => 1
)

[1] => Array
(
[id] => 2
[nom_entite] => ffff 
[nom_agence] => AG_22
[entite_abrev] => ffff
[entite_niveau] => 2
)
```

it's the list of element of Entite, i want to get this in table.

any help please!

Answer (score 0):

in the Repository:

```
 public function findAll(){
    $stmt = $this->getEntityManager()
    ->getConnection()
    ->prepare('select * from Entite ');
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    return $result;
}
```